# Can't position the imageview to the center

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, imageview, zooming

```
- (void)centerScrollViewContents {
    CGSize boundsSize = self.scrollView.bounds.size;
    CGRect contentsFrame = self.imageView.frame;

    if (contentsFrame.size.width < boundsSize.width) {
        contentsFrame.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - contentsFrame.size.width) / 2.0f;
    } else {
        contentsFrame.origin.x = 0.0f;
    }

    if (contentsFrame.size.height < boundsSize.height) {
        contentsFrame.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - contentsFrame.size.height) / 2.0f;
    } else {
        contentsFrame.origin.y = 0.0f;
    }

    self.imageView.frame = contentsFrame;
}
```

I called the the `conterScrollViewContents` method in `viewWillAppear`, but the imageView won't be positioned to the center of the scrollView.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct to me. Did you try to debug the values? Or maybe you haven't linked the imageView variable in the Interface Builder?

Comment: thanks your answer , i've just fixed this problem . i have not set the imageView's delegate .